How to Implement Conditional Deep and Shallow Logging in a Java Aspect
I am working on a Spring application where I need to implement logging using an Aspect. The logging should be conditionally deep or shallow based on an annotation parameter. Specifically:

Shallow Logging: Should log method parameters and return values without delving into nested objects. For example, it should print something like:
methodName started with parameters: { param1=SomeClass(field1=value1, field2=value2) }
If a field is a collection or a map, it should only print its type, not its contents:
SomeClass(field1=value1, field2=ArrayList)

Deep Logging: Should log detailed information about method parameters and return values, including nested objects but without listing the contents of collections or maps:
methodName started with parameters: { param1=SomeClass(field1=value1, field2=[valueA, valueB, valueC]) }


Here are the structures I've set up so far:
Annotation:
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Log {
    Depth depth() default Depth.SHALLOW;
}

Depth Enum:
public enum Depth {
    SHALLOW(1),
    DEEP(3);

    private final int level;

    Depth(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
}

Aspect:
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    @SuppressWarnings({"PMD.DataflowAnomalyAnalysis","PMD.AvoidCatchingThrowable"})
    @Around("@annotation(log) && execution(* *(..))")
    public Object logMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Log log) throws Throwable {
        CustomLogger logger = CustomLogger.getLogger(joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType());
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        Class<?> returnType = ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getReturnType();
        Map<String, Object> parameters = obtainParameters(joinPoint);

        int depth = log.depth().getLevel();
        // question part
        logger.info("{} started with parameters: {}", methodName, parameters);

        Object proceed;
        try {
            proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.info("{} failed with exception: {}, message: {}", methodName, e.toString(), e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        if (returnType == Void.TYPE) {
            logger.info("{} finished without return value.", methodName);
        } else {
            logger.info("{} finished with return value: {}", methodName, proceed);
        }
        return proceed;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> obtainParameters(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        String[] parameterNames = ((CodeSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getParameterNames();
        Object[] parameterValues = joinPoint.getArgs();
        for (int i=0; i < parameterNames.length && i < parameterValues.length; i++) {
            parameters.put(parameterNames[i], parameterValues[i]);
        }
        return parameters;
    }


}

Dependencies:
// aop 
implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.8' 
implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.8' 
// Spring Boot 
plugins { id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.9.RELEASE' }

Desired Output:

Shallow Mode:
methodName started with parameters: { param1=SomeClass(field1=value1, field2=ArrayList) }

Deep Mode:
methodName started with parameters: { param1=SomeClass(field1=value1, field2=[valueA, valueB, valueC]) }


Actual Output: Either too verbose, including nested collection contents.
Question: How can I implement the logging aspect to conditionally log deeply or shallowly without diving into nested collections or maps in deep mode?
Any insights or examples of a more robust approach to this logging problem would be greatly appreciated!

This problem is not related to AOP at all, it is about how to obtain certain printable object representations. Why you show unrelated code but hide the code creating such representations, is a mystery to me. Maybe it is hidden in your CustomLogger, maybe in a helper method of a class used by it. Or maybe, you are simply relying on whatever your logging framework (which one?) does by default. Like this, nobody can help you improve your code, because the code is invisible.

Thank you for your comment, @kriegaex. The problem indeed focuses on obtaining specific object representations for logging, and while it's not directly related to AOP, I tried to utilize AOP to intercept method calls and conditionally format logs. Actually, I solved problem with using reflection (clazz.getDeclaredFields()) without touching my custom logger

I think that reflection is unnecessary over-engineering and also slow. Probably, there is a better solution for your problem. As you did not show all relevant code, it is difficult to be more concrete here. Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Thank you..
